# ResultSet not open. Operation 'getString' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is off.?

Tags: java, database, derby

I am using apache derby and getting the above error here is my code, actually   I'm just not getting all the children under the parents, it only give me one level of children, so kindly tell me how to make tree parent and child but this gives only one level of child with above error

getting connection

```
public static Connection getConnection(){

    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();//
        //Get a connection
        connection  = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        connection.getAutoCommit();
    } catch (Exception except) {
        System.out.println(except);
    }
    return connection;
}
```

and error in second loop at last reading rs1

```
    Statement stmt;


        stmt = MainUI.getConnection().createStatement();
```

Comment: the answer accepted because the part you said one connection open for 1 statement i have tried to acess the same connection with other statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting the result sets is your problem, I believe.

To have two different result sets open, you must have two separate `Statement` instances, so each can have its own `ResultSet`. Otherwise, running the second query on the same `Statement` instance will close the first `ResultSet`.

See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579669/193453

Also, have a look at the Javadocs for the `java.sql.Statement` class:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet
>   object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been
>   generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the
>   Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet
>   object if an open one exists.

Comment: the answer accepted because the part you said one connection open for 1 statement i have tried to acess the same connection with other statement